# Vue JS Option element "selected" is only attribute, need it as property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to get an option to be selected by default if selected is present on the option object

This is what i have:

```
<template>
    <select v-model="model" :placeholder="placeholder">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value" :selected="option.selected">{{option.label}}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        model: {
            default: null
        },
        placeholder: {
            default: null
        },
        options: {
            default: null
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

This sets selected **attribute** correctly, i can see it in element explorer
This doesnt seem to work, since its only an attribute, if i check the element, the "selected" property on it is false!
How do i set selected **property** of the option element?

Comment: I think that you need to remove the `:selected="option.selected"` as it is supposed to be set by the v-model attribute

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the originally selected value to the value of the v-model, i.e.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        options: [
         {
             value: 'foo',
                label: 'foo label',
            },
         {
             value: 'bar',
                label: 'bar label',
            },
         {
             value: 'baz',
                label: 'baz label',
            },        
        ],
        selected: 'bar',
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <select v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{option.label}}</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the "data" property for my component was coming from somewhere else.
So i needed to find where it was coming from.